# Owebia Shipping selected country shipping list

Tags: magento-1.8

Owebia Shipping implement in my store.
how i disable country which i not want to shipped item.
there are no any selection for specific country selected list.
i want to ship item only in 50 country , other country not select from shipping step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select specific countries from system->configuration->general->general 
Select countries which you need to display on ship address dropdown.

Comment: we can delete this countries from database ?  there are another effect for this ?